# User-settable Root of Trust supported devices

Tags: boot, hardware, bootloader, aosp

As mentioned in [Android doc](https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/verifiedboot/device-state#user-settable-root-of-trust)

> Devices can optionally allow the user to configure the root of trust (for example, a public key). Devices can use this user-settable root of trust for Verified Boot instead of the built-in root of trust. This allows the user to install and use custom versions of Android without sacrificing the security improvements of Verified Boot.

and

> The Google Pixel 2 devices use this approach and the virtual partition is called avb_custom_key

So, Pixel 2 support this feature. I searched every where but not seen any list of phones that support **user-settable root of trust**

Has anyone list of android phones?